# Route Via Intermediate Waypoint - Passing a list of coordinates in via parameter

Tags: here-api

I need to pass a list of coordinates within parameters in **via parameter**, but i don't find the way. This is an example with only one pair of coordinates(lat, lng):

```
function calculateRoute (platform) {
  var router = platform.getRoutingService(null, 8),
    routeRequestParams = {
      routingMode: 'fast',
      transportMode: 'truck',
      origin: '36.87689,-2.44138',
      destination: '36.69630,-4.47968',
      via: '38.99112,-1.86902', //LIST HERE!!!
      return: 'polyline'
    };

  router.calculateRoute(
    routeRequestParams,
    onSuccessRoute,
    onError
  );
}
```

The url I'm hoping to get is like this:

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=
{API_KEY}&routingMode=fast&transportMode=truck&origin=36.87689,-2.44138&via=38.99112,-1.86902&via=37.95862,-1.15538&destination=36.69630,-4.47968&return=polyline
```

As you can see via is repeat in the URL.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript API does not (yet) support multiple routing waypoints with regards to the Routing v8 API, meaning, it does not support passing a list of coordinates to the `via` parameter.

So your best bet is to target the Routing v8 REST API directly, like follow, and build a polyline out of the response:

```sh
# Note: line breaks and spaces are for readability only (they need to be removed)

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?
  origin=52.550464,13.384223
  &transportMode=car
  &destination=52.477545,13.447395
  &via=52.529791,13.401389
  &via=52.513079,13.424392
  &via=52.487581,13.425079
  &apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps you, but

```
function calculateRouteFromAtoB (platform) {
  var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
      routeRequestParams = {
      mode: 'fastest;car',
      representation: 'display',
      routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
      maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
      waypoint0: '55.7520,37.6175',
      waypoint1: '55.8941,37.4439',
      waypoint2: '55.7982,37.9680'
      };
  router.calculateRoute(
      routeRequestParams,
      onSuccess,
      onError
  );
}
```

works for me.

Comment: I am using the latest Routing API and waypoints are not allowed. https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.3.1/api-reference-swagger.html